# How to launch 2 programs in parallel in Node.js in Linux

Tags: node.js, linux

How can I launch 2 programs in parallel in Node.js in Linux, wait for them to finish and get the output.

For example I want to run "rm -rf some/folder/" and run "ping google.com" at the same time from Node.js and get back the output after they finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CJS variant:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function getOutput(command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(command, (err, stdout) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(stdout);
    });
  });
}

(async function main() {
  try {
    const outputs = await Promise.all([
      getOutput('ping google.com'),
      getOutput('ping example.com'),
    ]);
    console.log(outputs.join('\n----------\n'));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

ESM variant with top-level `await`:

```js
import { exec } from 'child_process';

function getOutput(command) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    exec(command, (err, stdout) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve(stdout);
    });
  });
}

try {
  const outputs = await Promise.all([
    getOutput('ping google.com'),
    getOutput('ping example.com'),
  ]);
  console.log(outputs.join('\n----------\n'));
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```